# Como usar Conv2DTranspose do Keras?

Tags: python, machine-learning, keras

Alguém sabe como posso usar a `Conv2DTranspose` do keras encontrado nesse  link : https://keras.io/layers/convolutional/#conv2dtranspose ?

Poderiam me explicar o que cada parâmetro dessa função faz e como ela funciona por debaixo dos panos(qual algoritmo ela usa,etc) ? pois ainda estou meio confuso em relação ao funcionamento dela.

Estou querendo aumentar uma imagem, como parte do processo de uma rede neural convolucional . Por exemplo :

```
x.shape = (4,4,3)
```

Ou seja tem 4 linhas 4 colunas e 3 canais.
Gostaria de aumentar o x para uma matriz de (16,16,3) e dar um print na matriz logo após a função (caso seja possível) , ou seja:

```
output = Conv2DTranspose(x,....)
print(output)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Uma **convolução transposta** funciona de forma parecida a uma convolução tradicional. Ela normalmente é utilizada quando queremos obter um mapa de saída com uma dimensionalidade espacial (largura e altura) maior do que o de entrada de modo que esse mapeamento entre entrada~saída seja aprendido (por meio de filtros/kernels) da melhor forma possível para o problema em questão. Alguns exemplos comuns que utilizam deconvolução são redes convolucionais para problemas de segmentação (por exemplo, segmentar carros, pedestres, calçada em um cenário de veículos auto-dirigíveis).

(Extraí esses gifs e parte da explicação [desta resposta do Stack Exchange](https://datascience.stackexchange.com/questions/6107/what-are-deconvolutional-layers))
Considerando uma deconv com *stride* de 1 (isto é, saltando de 1 em 1 unidade no mapa de entrada), um o mapa de entrada 2x2 (azul) e um único kernel 3x3 (cinza se deslocando pelo mapa de entrada), o resultado será o mapa de saída 4x4 (verde). As regiões brancas são *paddings* de valor 0 (uma borda de valor 0 para que a convolução possa ser calculada).

[image: Deconvolução com stride de 1]

Considerando uma deconv com *stride* de 2, teríamos:

[image: Deconvolução com stride de 2]

Neste caso, o stride determina se há um espaçamento entre cada unidade do mapa de entrada.

Agora quanto aos parâmetros do Keras:

- **filters**: o número de filtros/kernels que serão aprendidos nesta camada. Nos exemplos que eu dei, só estávamos passando apenas 1 filtro. Esse parâmetro também vai definir o número de canais do mapa de saída. Se, no seu caso, você quer que o mapa de saída tenha valor 3, então `filters = 3`;
- **kernel_size**: o tamanho do filtro, da mesma forma que em uma convolução. No exemplo, o kernel tinha tamanho 3x3;
- **strides**: o salto/espaçamento que será utilizado;
- **padding**: "valid" ou "same", indica se vai ou não ser utilizado o padding / borda de zeros ao redor do mapa de entrada. "valid" implica que o kernel só vai ser posicionado em uma posição válida (ou seja, em que todas as posições do kernel caiam em cima de uma posição do mapa de entrada). Na prática, "valid" pode desconsiderar alguns pixels nas bordas do mapa de entrada. "same" fará com que seja adicionado padding necessário para posicionar o filtro na primeira posição do mapa de entrada.
- **output_padding**: é apenas um padding que é adicionado ao redor do mapa de saída.

Os outros parâmetros são comuns a camadas convolucionais.

Ao final do link que você mandou na pergunta, há um cálculo para saber o tamanho do mapa final, dado o mapa inicial e os parâmetros:

```
new_rows = ((rows - 1) * strides[0] + kernel_size[0]
            - 2 * padding[0] + output_padding[0])
new_cols = ((cols - 1) * strides[1] + kernel_size[1]
            - 2 * padding[1] + output_padding[1])
```

Por exemplo, fazer o mapa de entrada `4x4x3` virar um `12x12x3`, você pode utilizar:

`output = Conv2DTranspose(filters=3, kernel_size=(5,5), strides=2, padding="same")(x)`

Comment: Obrigado pela resposta, foi bem esclarecedora.